# Saving variables while changing View Controllers

Tags: swift

I'm making an app, and it saves a score to a variable, and when you click a button it adds points to the score and displays it on a label. My problem is, I have 3 Views Controllers, each hooked up to the same class. To segue to a different view controller, I just made a button in the storyboard that moves to the other view. My trouble is when I move to this new view the score resets, and when I go back to my first view the score resets again. I believe the problem is whenever I switch views, the class re-runs the code, which is where I declared the scoring variable to equal zero. How can I have it so when I change views my score stays like it was? One last thing: I tried looping a print command to tell me my score, and when I added a score in the first view, it would show up as expected, however when I switched views and added a score to the second view, it would print my first score, then my second score over and over again. Every time I switch views it will print the score from all the previous scores, as well as my current one.

Comment: just make use of AppDelegate class to store variables and access them globally in any viewController

Comment: Do hooking 3 VCs to same class have specific purpose?

Comment: @laxmankhanal , I am using the 3 view Controllers on the same class because I have a lot of data to pass between the Views, and didn't want to have to create Global class variables for all of them. It seems that might not be any easier than what I'm doing right now though. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: don't use a class use a struct. Have you tried the answer at the duplicated question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the values Globally in App delegate

just make a var variable of any like string , int as

```
var myScores = Int()
```

and now pass the values in myScores

in source ViewController 
make a object of Appdelegate as below

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
```

and pass values as

```
appDelegate.myScores = your int value
```

now to access that value in destinationController

```
 let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let myOldScores : Int = appDelegate.myScores
```

Comment: Don’t get me wrong, AppDelegate is the place to initialize these, but making AppDelegate the primary class that will contain the logic for these services is bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think one the best way to do this is using singleton class,

```
final class GameDetail {

    // MARK: Shared Instance

    static let shared = GameDetail()

    // Can't init is singleton
    private init() { }

    // MARK: Local Variable  
    var score : Int = 0

}
```

I know, it’s tempting to use the AppDelegate instance as your “global” singleton instance, but don’t do this. Create specific and separate singletons if that is what you need

Comment: why not simply `static let shared = GameDetail()` ?

Comment: Your syntax is wrong should be = not :